# How can I quit the for loop if value doesn't exist?

Tags: python

I've made a function that calculates distance using 4 values: lat1, lon1, lat2, and lat2

```
def greatcirclem(lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2):                           
    lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2=map(np.deg2rad,[lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2])
    dlon=lon2-lon1 
    sint1=np.sin(lat1)
    sint2=np.sin(lat2)
    cost1=np.cos(lat1)
    cost2=np.cos(lat2)
    codln=np.cos(dlon)
    aaa=np.arccos(sint1*sint2+cost1*cost2*codln)
    ccc=np.rad2deg(aaa)
    km_greatcircle=ccc*1.852*60
    m_greatcircle=km_greatcircle*100
    return m_greatcircle
```

When I apply this function in a `for` loop an error occurs when lat2,lon2 doesn't exist.

I mean cause I just select values from n rows and n+1 rows in my function, n+1 rows will be out of range at the end of part.

When the values don't exist how can I quit the `for` loop?

I'll attach my for loop code also.

```
for row in range(min(data3.index),max(data3.index)):
    data3.loc[row+1,'diff_m'] = greatcirclem(data3.loc[row,'lat'], data3.loc[row,'lon'], data3.loc[row+1,'lat'], data3.loc[row+1,'lon'])
```

Comment: Couldn't you do `for row in range(min(data3.index),max(data3.index) - 1):` ? As an aside, this code seems really unidiomatic, be careful!

Comment: maybe what you want is a try: except: block round your code? if it fails.. catch the exception and handle (?)

Comment: Not related to the question you’re asking but if km_greatcircle is the length in kilometres and m_greatcircle is the length in meters shouldn’t you multiply by 1000 and not by 100.

Comment: Oh, i didn't recognize that thank U

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps there are two solutions:

1) Write your function with default values?

`def greatcirclem(lat1=0,lon1=0,lat2=0,lon2=0):`

2) Put a conditional inside your for loop (more expensive, though):

```
      if lat2 and lon2:
          data3.loc[row+1,'diff_m'] = etc.
      else:
          continue #i.e. move on to the next data set OR insert arbitarty value
```

It sounds like you're processing a data file where some entries might be missing? So you can either fudge in some values, or stick in a value that is so far out of bounds that it behaves as an error signal, or you could throw an exception... i.e. halt program execution because bad data. All depends on the case at hand.